# (one piece) バウンドマン means Bounce man or Bound man?

Tags: anime

If you never watch one piece, I need to tell you this first:

`Gear Fourth in One piece anime is a technic where luffy's body get bigger like a balloon (luffy is a gum man) and during that form he is not able to stand correctly and always bouncing (I believe he can't stop the bounce).`

I already checked using google translated `バウンド` could be translated as `Bound` or `Bounce`.

From wikia:

`Luffy's first Gear Fourth form is called Boundman (弾む男 (バウンドマン) Baundoman?, Viz: Bounce Man): Luffy's proportions become warped and his body becomes much larger in size, with his arms, upper torso, and legs coated in Busoshoku Haki.`

so which one the better translation for this? or the both does make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the linked [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOrlCN8-1v8), he clearly shouts "バウンドマン" and the subtitle reads "Bounce-Man".

The ド in "バウンドマン" is pronounced as [doh] and it should be written as "Bound-Man". However, if you use it, it could be understood as

> A man bound (tied) with rope or something else so that he can't move.

That's why "Bounce-Man" is used in English.